# Simulating drift in the data

Tags: regression, time-series, simulation, stationarity

I want to add drift in the data over time. I want to have real-valued independent variables ($x\in\mathbb{R}^{t}$) and a real-valued response variable ($y\in\mathbb{R}^t$)?

I want to simulate

$y=f_t(x)=a(t)x+b$

where $a(t)$ is a function of time and controls drift.

How can I add simulate data using the above equation?

**What do I mean by Drift?**

The regression line shifts over time i.e. the line that explains the linear relation between $x$ and $y$ shifts (drifts).

[image].

The above plot is taken from the [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221506213_Drift-Aware_Ensemble_Regression).

**Remark**

I want to simulate data so I can perform regression with non-stationary variables. I was unable to find dataset where $y$ is real-valued and there is drift. There are few dataset where $y$ is categorical and there is drift for example [here](http://www.liaad.up.pt/kdus/products/datasets-for-concept-drift).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by drift?

Comment: I want to have non-stationarity variables i.e. the assumption of constant mean is violated.

Comment: This is still unclear. Are the data somehow ordered? Eg, are they a sequence of measurements over time? We have a variety of threads about simulating time-series data (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simulation+time-series?sort=votes&pageSize=50)). Would any of those help you?

Comment: Yes it is a sequence of measurements over time.

Comment: Can you specify how time comes into this? I don't see a time variable anywhere, eg. What kind of structure are you after? Can you put it in ARIMA terms? (Ie, an autoregressive structure, or a moving average structure, etc.)

Comment: Here is an [example](https://www.reed.edu/economics/parker/312/tschapters/S13_Ch_4.pdf). Does this help?

Comment: I would say this does help, but it differs substantially from what I thought you were asking. I thought you meant the errors were nonstationary over time. Now you seem to mean the errors are independent (w/i a given time slice), but the relationship b/t X & Y is changing over time.

Comment: @gung Yes I want "b/t X & Y is changing over time"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but below is some R code that I've put together demonstrating how to simulate non-stationary data (with breaks). I simulate two basic series; an AR(2) process and an AR(1) process. I then introduce various shocks to each series, including an on-off intercept shift, and **also fundamental changes to the data generating process (DGP) - by introducing an independent variable**, increasing the error variance, **changing the trend slope**. If you're more specific (and clearer!), maybe we can refine this answer. I admit, this is a programming answer, but there is a small amount of statistics required. Cheers.

**Update:** Combine both aspects highlighted in bold to create a series that is dependent on another variable and for which the fundamental relationship changes over time (i.e. change at some time t from **x = alpha + beta1 * y** to **x = alpha + beta2 * y**, where beta1 does not equal beta2).

**R Code**

```
# Part 1 - Set the parameters

# Constant terms
alpha1 <- 5
alpha2 <- 10

# AR coefficients
phi1 <- c(0.80,0.15)
phi2 <- c(0.85)

# Number of periods
n <- 500          

# Scaling factor (coefficient) on trend
scale1 <- 0.01         
scale2 <- 0.07

# Initial data values
x <- c(rep(0,n))
z <- c(rep(0,n))

# Error terms
w <- rnorm(n,mean=0,sd=1)
v <- rnorm(n,mean=0,sd=5)

shock1 <- 150
shock2 <- 0.02
shocks <- TRUE # Switch this on/off to see the effect of shocks

# Part 2 - Simulate the data

for(t in 3:n) {
  if(shocks==TRUE){
    if(t<250){
      x[t] <- alpha1 + phi1[1] * x[t-1] + phi1[2] * x[t-2] + w[t] + scale1*t  # AR(2) with constant and trend
      z[t] <- alpha2 + phi2[1] * z[t-1] + v[t] + scale2*t                     # AR(1) with constant and trend    
    }else if(t==250){
      x[t] <- alpha1 + shock1 + phi1[1] * x[t-1] + phi1[2]* x[t-2] + w[t] + scale1*t  # Intercept shock on
      z[t] <- alpha2 + phi2[1] * z[t-1] + v[t] + scale2*t
    }
    else if(t==251){
      x[t] <- alpha1 - shock1 + phi1[1] * x[t-1] + phi1[2]* x[t-2] + w[t] + scale1*t  # Intercept shock off
      z[t] <- alpha2 + phi2[1] * z[t-1] + v[t] + scale2*t
    }else if(t>251){
      x[t] <- alpha1 + phi1[1] * x[t-1] + phi1[2] * x[t-2] + w[t] + scale1*t  + 0.02 * z[t-12] # Shock to DGP (Exog variable)
      z[t] <- alpha2 + phi2[1] * z[t-1] + 5*v[t] + (scale2+shock2*t/100)*t                     # Shock to DGP (Error and trend)   
    }  
  }else{
    x[t] <- alpha1 + phi1[1] * x[t-1] + phi1[2] * x[t-2] + w[t] + scale1*t  # AR(2) with constant and trend (no shocks)
    z[t] <- alpha2 + phi2[1] * z[t-1] + v[t] + scale2*t                     # AR(1) with constant and trend (no shocks)  
  }
}

# Part 3 - View the data 
# Note: discard some of the initial values (required due to constant terms)

par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot.ts(x[1:500],main="Simulated Series 1") 
plot.ts(z[1:500],main="Simulated Series 2")
plot.ts(x[100:400],main="Simulated Series 1")
plot.ts(z[100:400],main="Simulated Series 2")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

You should get something like this:
[image]

**Update 2:** Maybe this is closer to what you are asking? Here I've simulated an AR(2) model for the independent variable (x) and used a static regression model to simulate the dependent variable (z). The "beta" coefficient in the regression model changes (abruptly) over time after every 1000 periods or so.

```
# Part 1 - Set the parameters

# Constant terms
alpha1 <- 5
alpha2 <- 10

# AR coefficients
phi1 <- c(0.80,0.15)
phi2 <- c(0.85)

# Number of periods
n <-6002          

# Scaling factor (coefficient) on trend
scale1 <- 0.01         

# Initial data values
x <- c(rep(0,n))
z <- c(rep(0,n))

# Error terms
w <- rnorm(n,mean=0,sd=1)
v <- rnorm(n,mean=0,sd=5)

# Part 2 - Simulate the data

for(t in 3:n) {
    if(t<1000){
      x[t] <- alpha1 + phi1[1] * x[t-1] + phi1[2] * x[t-2] + w[t] + scale1*t  # AR(2) with constant and trend 
      z[t] <- alpha2 + phi2[1] * x[t] + v[t]                                  # Static regression model with constant and trend    
    }else if(t<2000){
      x[t] <- alpha1 + phi1[1] * x[t-1] + phi1[2] * x[t-2] + w[t] + scale1*t  # AR(2) with constant and trend
      z[t] <- alpha2 + (phi1[1] -0.2) * x[t] + v[t]                           # Static regression model with constant and trend    
    }else if(t<3000){
      x[t] <- alpha1 + phi1[1] * x[t-1] + phi1[2] * x[t-2] + w[t] + scale1*t  # AR(2) with constant and trend
      z[t] <- alpha2 + (phi1[1] -0.4) * x[t] + v[t]                           # Static regression model with constant and trend   
    }else if(t<4000){
      x[t] <- alpha1 + phi1[1] * x[t-1] + phi1[2] * x[t-2] + w[t] + scale1*t  # AR(2) with constant and trend
      z[t] <- alpha2 + (phi1[1] -0.8) * x[t] + v[t]                           # Static regression model with constant and trend    
    }else if(t<5000){
      x[t] <- alpha1 + phi1[1] * x[t-1] + phi1[2] * x[t-2] + w[t] + scale1*t  # AR(2) with constant and trend
      z[t] <- alpha2 + (phi1[1] -1.2) * x[t] + v[t]                           # Static regression model with constant and trend    
    }else{
      x[t] <- alpha1 + phi1[1] * x[t-1] + phi1[2] * x[t-2] + w[t] + scale1*t  # AR(2) with constant and trend
      z[t] <- alpha2 + (phi1[1] -1.4) * x[t] + v[t]                           # Static regression model with constant and trend    
    }
}

# Part 3 - View the data 
# Note: discard some of the initial values (required due to constant terms)

par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot.ts(x[100:6000],main="Simulated Series 1")
plot.ts(z[100:6000],main="Simulated Series 2")
plot(x[100:5999],z[100:5999],main="Scatter plot (levels)")
abline(lsfit(x[100:999],z[100:999]),col="red")
abline(lsfit(x[1000:1999],z[1000:1999]),col="red")
abline(lsfit(x[2000:2999],z[2000:2999]),col="red")
abline(lsfit(x[3000:3999],z[3000:3999]),col="red")
abline(lsfit(x[4000:4999],z[4000:4999]),col="red")
abline(lsfit(x[5000:5999],z[5000:5999]),col="red")
plot(-100:100,-100:100,col="white",xlab = "x",ylab = "z",main="Scatter plot (differences)")
abline(lsfit(diff(x[100:999]),diff(z[100:999])),col="red")
abline(lsfit(diff(x[1000:1999]),diff(z[1000:1999])),col="red")
abline(lsfit(diff(x[2000:2999]),diff(z[2000:2999])),col="red")
abline(lsfit(diff(x[3000:3999]),diff(z[3000:3999])),col="red")
abline(lsfit(diff(x[4000:4999]),diff(z[4000:4999])),col="red")
abline(lsfit(diff(x[5000:5999]),diff(z[5000:5999])),col="red")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

You should get something like this:

[image]

Comment: My interpretation is in my [comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/330199/simulating-drift-in-the-data#comment625594_330199) above. I don't think the idea is ARMA errors, but an interaction between the X's & time.

Comment: Thanks @gung Hmm... Well, my interpretation was that the two variables should be a function of time. In this case, my code does that, hence why the variables are trending upwards. I also thought that one variable should depend on the other, so I covered this in the line of code where it says `# Shock to DGP (Exog variable)` Regarding the shocks, I introduced different types of shocks to cover both abrupt changes and gradual changes. True, I include lagged variables, which isn't necessary, but this doesn't affect the overall idea (and wasn't meant to be the focus!). Happy to rearrange. Cheers.

Comment: @gung There are many variations. I tried to cover enough to make the answer complete. For example, I think a graduate change of a slope parameter on an independent variable would be a nice one. My code is easily adaptable to demonstrate that.

Comment: @GraemeWalsh The gradient will be the same for any two time intervals. For example `plot((y[1:400])~x[1:400,1])` or `plot((y[1:100])~x[1:100,1])`,...Only scale differs

Comment: @Waqas You can change the relationship in many different ways. If you want to change the slope over time, just make the coefficient on the independent variable change over time (as a shock). Only minimal changes to the code are required. I trust you can adjust this to your need - as I have covered a lot already (that was the idea, to make the code demonstrative and flexible!). Also, I think you'll need to difference the variables before looking at the scatter plot.